# React router dom v6.10 redirect function isn't working (programmatically redirect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I've been using `redirect` method from `react-router-dom`, since v5, but now it's not working. I've tried `useNavigate` hook, but then I can't get params through `useParams` hook. It just doesn't make any redirection to the component defined in the routes. My app was created with `create-react-app`. Here's my configuration:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Person from './entities/person/Person';
import UpdatePerson from './entities/person/UpdatePerson';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Person />} />
      <Route path='/update/:id' element={<UpdatePerson />} />
    </Routes>

  );
}
```

Then in a component rendered inside PersonComponent, I have a button who calls the next function:

```
const handleEdit = (id) => {
  console.log('Edit clicked, with ID: ', id);
  redirect(`/update/${id}`);
}
...
...
...
<input
  type="button"
  value="Edit"
  onClick={() => handleEdit(person.idPerson)}
/>
```

I have imported `import { redirect } from "react-router-dom"` inside the component who calls the previous function. And if I access directly to the route to update component, it works as expected, the only problem is the redirection. What am I missing? Because even in the docs they recommend to use `redirect` instead of `useNavigate` hook: [Redirect - React Router DOM docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect)

Or maybe I should use `useNavigate` hook, and there's other way to get URL params. Just don't tell me to use `useLocation` because in the docs they say that it returns raw data, and they can provide a better abstraction.

It works now, by using `useNavigate` instead of `redirect` function, for redirection, and `useParams` to get params in the next component, but I want to know if it's possible to use redirect, as it's the recommended option in the docs.

Comment: FWIW I think you are conflating the new [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) utility function which was introduced in RRDv6.4 with the older [`Redirect`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) component from RRDv4/5. They are completely unrelated.

Comment: @DrewReese... Oops, my bad, thank you for noticing it and taking some of your time to link the docs in here. But, i reviewed the code from an old project, which I made by reading the docs carefully, and I used a programmatically redirect by using `redirect`function, and in package.json, this is my version: "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0", I've never used the Redirect component, but Now I just can't find anything about that function in react-router-dom V5 docs haha.

Comment: Was it perhaps a custom utility function you'd written using a custom exported `history` object (*e.g. `export const history = createBrowserHistory();`*)? Something like `const redirect = target => history.replace(target);`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `redirect` utility function is only validly used in a data router route's `loader` or `action` functions, and is shorthand for returning a 302 response.

```js
new Response("", {
  status: 302,
  headers: {
    Location: someUrl,
  },
});
```

It's not a replacement to the `navigate` function. You've misunderstood the recommendation, emphasis is mine:

> It's recommended to use `redirect` ***in loaders and actions*** rather than
> `useNavigate` in your components when the redirect is in response to
> data.

You should still use the `useNavigate` hook in the React component code to effect a navigation action from a callback.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const handleEdit = (id) => {
  console.log('Edit clicked, with ID: ', id);
  navigate(`/update/${id}`, { replace: true }); // <-- redirect
};

...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, but I've used it also in a fetch promise chain:
`.... }).then((data) => {  console.log('Person has been updated with response: ', data); redirect('/'); }).catch((error) => { ....`
But it also doesn't work, I had to use navigate instead.

Comment: @elG If the Promise chain isn't in a route's loader or action function then `redirect` still won't work. If the Promise chain is in a React component, then the `useNavigate` hook is used and `navigate` is called. Do you mind editing your post to include the more accurate version of the code you are trying to use?

Comment: Oh, that's pretty clear now, I was confused by the part in the docs you quoted in your answer, as it  says "components", and "in response to data", I thought it was referring to retrieving data and updating the component according to it. But with your explanation, it's pretty clear now. At this moment, the code is working as expected by using `useNavigate`, I don't think it's necessary to put more code in there, because you nailed it with your explanation, and that extra part was just a handleSubmit function for a submit event in a form, something pretty standard.

Comment: @elG I see, well the RRD docs do tend to be a little confusing at times in their wording. I think the gist of that quote might have been intended more as something like "return `redirect` directly from the loader instead of waiting for the page to load and using `navigate` to redirect.... in response to having fetched data", but that's probably just as confusing.