# In react router redirecting is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router-Dom version "^6.17.0" and I am trying to redirect users to the login page if they are not logged in.

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export function authUsers() {
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    console.log("not logged in");
    // window.location.href = "/login?message=Please login first";
    redirect("/login");
    return null;
  }

  console.log("logged in");
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @satvir singh, could you please add code pen or code sand box to help you better

Comment: @AbhijeetAbnave here is the github repo - https://github.com/stvrdeol/vanlife , currently i am using javascript way of redirecting. Host is a protected route in which user need to be logged in.

Comment: please have a look on following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049065/react-router-dom-v6-10-redirect-function-isnt-working-programmatically-redirec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router dom v6.10 redirect function isn't working (programmatically redirect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049065/react-router-dom-v6-10-redirect-function-isnt-working-programmatically-redirec)

Comment: @AbhijeetAbnave it does not solves my problem as i am using redirect function inside the loader. i can't use useNavigate() hook either.

Comment: you can use history object then

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useNavigate` instead of redirect.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

 export function authUsers() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
   const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");

   if (!isLoggedIn) {
   console.log("not logged in");
    navigate("/login");
    return null;
  }
 console.log("logged in");
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ***return*** a value or Response object from the loader. ***Return*** the redirect response.

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export function authUsers() {
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return redirect("/login"); // <-- return redirect response
  }
  return null;
}
```

Or more succinctly

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export function authUsers() {
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");

  return isLoggedIn ? null : redirect("/login");
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still it is not working

Comment: @satvirsingh Can you please be more specific, anything other than "it's not working" would probably be helpful. Where is `authUsers` being used/called in your code? Can you edit your post to include a complete [mcve] so we can see more of what may be going on with your code?